# How do I serialize and deserialize arrayList object?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io, arraylist, deserialization

In my program, the input objects are stored in an arrayList. The problem is I lose all the data after I close the application.

That's why I want to jump a step further to store those objects on disk so that no data is lost after closing the application. Eventually I want to read the file. The class I am working on is: `ReaderWriter`.

[I have come to know that before writing and reading file, I must serialize and de-serialize objects. I have no idea how to do this. I have searched online, mostly they have done it inside the main method. But in my case I have different class for setObject and getObject, that's why I am confused.]

PeopleInfo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("WELCOME TO MY PERSONAL DATABASE\n\n");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<PeopleObject> peopleObject = new ArrayList<PeopleObject>();
    String name;
    int age;
    int option;

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("1. Enter info\n"
                + "2. Print them out\n"
                + "3. Exit\n"
                + "*********"
                + "*********\n");
        option = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                PeopleObject p_object = new PeopleObject();
                System.out.println("Enter your friends name:");
                p_object.setName(input.nextLine());
                System.out.println("Enter age: ");
                p_object.setAge(input.nextInt());

                peopleObject.add(p_object);
                System.out.println("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Name \tage");
                for (PeopleObject printPeopleObject : peopleObject) {
                    System.out.println(printPeopleObject);

                }
                System.out.println("\n\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                return;
        }

    }

}
```

PeopleObject:

```
private String name;
private int age;

public PeopleObject() {
    this.name = null;
    this.age = 0;

}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name + "\t\t" + age;
}
```

ReaderWriter:

```
public class ReaderWriter {
        //I want to use this class for serialization and deserialization object
        //writing those data into file and reading them
    }
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html .

Comment: VGR, I have looked at this similar kind, but may be I am too dumb to figure out specifically how to implement it in my program. Because I see I I have arrayList in my main class and objects are in different class. Exactly where I have to serialize and de-serialize it I dont know.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`.

You `PeopleObject` must implement `Serializable`.

```
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("name"));
stream.writeObject(yourArrayList);

ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("name"));
yourArrayList = (List<PeopleObject>)stream.readObject();
```

Comment: You will need a small cast at the reading: yourArrayList = (ArrayList)stream.readObject();

Comment: Yes. Forgot about that. Will fix it.

Comment: talex, just became emotional and put an upvote. But the truth is that I didn't get that much, almost nothing. My arrayList is in my main class, then how can I implement it in PeopleObject class. Also I dont know what List<PeopleObject does do, because I didn't create that anywhere.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. I don't understand a word. And calm down before do it :)

Comment: what is "yourArrayList"? and "List<PeopleObject" is in my main class? how can List<PeopleObject> can be used outside the main class? because I created arrayList in my main class.

Comment: In first part `yourArrayList` is list that you want to save.In second it is result of load. In your code it is called `peopleObject`. You can use list outside of main by making it global. Just declare it before main method and make it static. It is bad design but will work.